# trying to use ggplot to plot a simple linear regression with one categorical variable, and get a regression line on plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm

I am trying to use ggplot to graph 3 linear models:

```
model = lm(dep_delay ~ season, data = data)
model2 = lm(dep_delay ~ carrier, data = data)
model3 = lm(dep_delay ~ origin, data = data)
```

My data is structured as follow:

```
season origin carrier dep_delay
1 winter    EWR      UA         2
2 winter    LGA      UA         4
3 winter    JFK      AA         2
4 winter    JFK      B6        -1
5 winter    LGA      DL        -6
6 winter    EWR      UA        -4
```

I am trying to use this line of code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = season, y = dep_delay)) + geom_boxplot() + labs(x="season") + geom_smooth(method = "lm",se=FALSE, col = "blue")
```

it is giving me the plot I want, but is not putting a line on the plot, how do i get the line to appear?

Answer (score 0):

geom_smooth() fails to fit the line given x is not numeric. You can recode season to number and use as.numeric(season) when specifying aes.